# Get annotation value from enum constant

Tags: java, enums, annotations, enumerator

I have an enumerator and a custom annotation that represents the enumerator's description:

```
public @interface Description {

   String name() default "";

}
```

Enumerator:

```
public enum KeyIntermediaryService {
     @Description(name="Descrizione WorldCheckService")
     WORLDCHECKSERVICE,
     @Description(name="blabla")
     WORLDCHECKDOWNLOAD,
     @Description(name="")
     WORLDCHECKTERRORISM,
     // ...
}
```

How can I get the enumerator description from within another class?

Comment: this question is already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947125/calling-a-enum-value-from-another-class-within-the-same-java-project)

Comment: Just like you get the annotation from an arbitrary field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this, e.g. to get the description for the `WORLDCHECKSERVICE` enum value:

```
Description description = KeyIntermediaryService.class
        .getField(KeyIntermediaryService.WORLDCHECKSERVICE.name())
        .getAnnotation(Description.class);

System.out.println(description.name());
```

You would have to change your annotation's retention policy to runtime though:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@interface Description {
    String name() default "";
}
```

Comment: Is `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)` the reason for getting a NullPointer with my code? I mean could you elaborate the use and reason to use it more.

Comment: Yup, that is indeed the cause. The default retention policy is [`CLASS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html#CLASS), i.e. the annotation will not be available for inspection at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Followed the link [Is it possible to read the value of a annotation in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296910/is-it-possible-to-read-the-value-of-a-annotation-in-java) to produce the following code -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     for (Field field : KeyIntermediaryService.class.getFields()) {
         Description description = field.getAnnotation(Description.class);
         System.out.println(description.name());
     }
}
```

Ya but this code would produce an NPE, unless as specifed by @Robby in his answer that you need to change your annotation to have a `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)` marked for `Description`.

The reason for that being stated in the answer here - [How do different retention policies affect my annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107970/how-do-different-retention-policies-affect-my-annotations)

Comment: Can you tell me wich Field i have to import? Thx.

Comment: `java.lang.reflect.Field`